# Fantasy cartoon with characters transforming into animals matching their personalities; evil woman transforms into a shark

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I am looking for a cartoon series I watched in the late 80s or early 90s, about characters that are given powers to transform into animals of their character.

An example is the one of the good guys could transform into a lion because he was full of courage, another character could transform into an eagle because he loved flying, and another had the power of knowledge because he was intelligent.

One evil character in the cartoon is called Firolina she could transform into a shark.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169744/80s-90s-anime-film-where-people-transform-into-their-animal-powers-i-e-man-ch (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 13):

I believe you are talking about [*Visionaries: Knights of the Magical Light*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visionaries:_Knights_of_the_Magical_Light).  It's from late in 1987, and only lasted for 13 episodes.

- Leoric had a Lion totem of Wisdom
- Arzon had the Eagle of Knowledge
- and so on.

This image might help verify it for you:
[image: Image of a bunch of the Visionaries]

The clincher is the shark you mentioned; Her name was actually Virulina.
[image: Virulina wearing purple armor showing her Shark Totem]

Comment: Loved that show! Visiiiiiiioooonaries, magical warriors of Light!!!

Comment: I don't know anything about that show, but I've got to ask - what use is a shark morph in non-water battles?

Comment: @Jenayah: beacuse she used to fight against one of the good guys, who could transform into a dolphin. By the way, great show, so bad it was short lived...