# 80's/90's anime film where people transform into their animal powers. i.e man changed into cheetah to run faster

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

When I was about 3 or 4 years old I remember watching a cartoon film, probably around 1991/92, where the characters could turn into their animal powers.

I specifically remember one scene where a character (I think it was male) turns into a cheetah so that he can run fast through a gauntlet of barriers that were smashing into the ground.

I'm sure that each character could turn into a different animal based on their personality etc.

I would love to find out what this film was.

It may have even been a series.

Comment: [Centurions?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_wtfQfP9ao&feature=youtu.be&t=33s)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *[Visionaries (Knights of the Magical Light)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visionaries:_Knights_of_the_Magical_Light)*.

In this scene you can see the character who portrays a cheetah running through a series of gates at high speed

Comment: I think this is probably it! thank you! i must of confused two cartoons together as i was only 3 or 4 when i watched it.

Comment: done. thanks again.